How to execute as much of a snakemake workflow as possible?
I'm using snakemake for orchestrating a data pipeline from multiple sources. In the beginning of the workflow, there are several rules that deals with just one source. Eventually there is a rule that has a dependency on all of the sources. So, imagine the following graph:
A1-->A2--\
          C1-->C2
B1-->B2--/

Sometimes, A1 is ready to go, but B1 isn't. Sometimes it is the other way around. Sometimes both are ready. Either of these parts of the pipeline can take awhile to run and use a fair amount of resources, so I'd like to get as much done as possible, even if not all of it is able to be done right away.
I have tried --until, --keep-going, and --omit-from, but none of these options seem to let me do what I want. I'm totally fine with snakemake exiting such a situation with an error code and message, so long as it tries to do as much of the workflow as possible.

A bit more context: The snakemake call in happening in a crontab, repeated a few times a day. I want to do a single call because at any given moment, I don't know what is ready and what is not ready.

I am not sure if this fulfills all your requirements, but if you increase the priorities of the rules A# and B#, these rules will be run befor snakemake considers C1.

The graph indicates the dependencies, so C1 wouldn't run without both A2 and B2 being complete.

ok, then i missunderstood. I thought you have n files which are going to be processed via A and n files which are processed by path B and your goal was to process most of them befor the first file-combination enters the C path. Sry, my bad.
But to be honest, then I dont get the problem. What is wrong with a default snakemake called every x hours via cron? Maybe you can clearify a bit further, or someone else has to jump in.

If I do snakemake A2 B2, but A1 isn't ready, then B2 won't get made, and that process might take an hour to complete, so that's lost time that I'm trying to snip to get my final product faster. I am currently doing for task in A2 B2; do snakemake $task & done ; wait, but then I lose the resource management if both A2 and B2 go at the same time.

Ok, I think I got it now (I hope ^^). How about, a Python function at the beginning of your script? It outputs a list of files that should be created (input for the first rule "rule all"). The function checks if A1 and B1 are present. If so it outputs C2, if only A1 then it outputs A2, and if only B1 it outputs B2. If X hours later A1 gets available snakemake would see that B2 is already created, thus runs only the A-Path, and continues with the C-Path. Would that work?

Interesting. I'd probably give the rule a name like "magic" or something, but that might be doable. Basically, a rule that dynamically adjusts its input based on what's available. Literally, a moving target!

I've been playing with this idea now, and developing it and it is working out fairly nicely, although it does require having knowledge of which upstream dependencies you'd need to check. I'll post an refined "answer" later today demonstrating it. This all can be done better by walking the DAG, so I'm thinking of submitting a patch for an --any command-line option.

This approach might be useful. It's a bit of a hack but it does work in Snakemake 8.11 which I just used to test it. Start the workflow going with snakemake -c1 and then create the four input files in any order you like.
# A Snakemake workflow which requires four inputs, but can be run immediately
# so as to wait for any missing inputs to appear and process them as they do.
# The hack is to use "threads: 0" on the waiting job which allows all the waiting
# tasks to run immediately, even if there is only one core allocated. You must run
# Snakemake with the "--cores" option, not "--jobs", for this to work.

SAMPLES = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

rule finalize:
    output: "final.txt"
    input:  "combined.txt"
    shell:
        "nl {input} > {output}"

# This rule can only run once A.txt, B.txt, C.txt and D.txt are ready.
rule combine:
    output: "combined.txt"
    input:  expand("{s}_processed.txt", s=SAMPLES)
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"

# This rule represents a long processing step
rule preprocess:
    output: "{s}_processed.txt"
    input:  "{s}.txt"
    shell:
        "sleep 30 ; sort {input} > {output}"

rule waitforit:
    output:  "{s,.}.txt"
    threads: 0
    shell:
        """while test ! -e {output} ; do
            sleep 5
           done
        """

